# Spring HibernateTemplate autocommit false

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I need to fetch 1 lakh record from one table and insert into another table in batch manner.I am using Spring3 hibernate template for inserting.i need to commit only after every 100 records but hibernate template commits every record when it is inserting.How to do the commit afetr batch insertion using hibernate template or how to disable autocommit in hibernate template.

```
for(everey iteration){
count = count+1;
getHibernateTemplate().setAlwaysNewSession(true);
CurrentPlan plan = new currentplan();
Rate rate = new rate();
plan.setName("aa");
rate.setRate(2);

getHibernateTemplate.saveorUpdate(plan )
getHibernateTemplate.saveorUpdate(rate )
if(count==100){
getHibernateTemplate.flush();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: HibernateTemplate does not commit after each insertion. It doesn't commit at all. Show us your code.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `setAlwaysUseNewSession()`? If so, why do you set it to true, since it does exactly what you don't want to do?

Answer (score -1):

diable auto commits in hibernate :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
```